# Java - Pass JLabel to Integer

Tags: java

I want to pass the JLabel to Integer, The following code does not work even with **Integer.valueOf()** and **Integer.parse()**

This are the following code I've Tried:

Test 1:

```
JLabel life = new JLabel("204");
int x = Integer.valueOf(life).intValue();
```

Test 2:

```
JLabel life = new JLabel("204");
int x = Integer.parseInt(life);
```

Comment: ```Integer.valueOf(life.getText())```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java

Comment: @spi just saw your profile and you have like 10+ years of experience, so reputation points really don't matter at that much experience i guess. Anyways, happy coding :)

Comment: @FarhanQasim real world points are much more useful :)

Comment: @spi bless you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't magically convert a `Label` to `Integer`.

However you can get the string of that label and then convert.

```
JLabel life = new JLabel("204");
int x = Integer.parseInt(life.getText());
```

Note that, you'll be succeed when there is proper text. For ex

`"203", "34343"` works but not `"A2342"`

Comment: Ahh.. The thing is get the string first before to convert. Finally it worked!! :)